# Throwing MojoFailureException wont causes a "BUILD FAILURE" message to be displayed when running a plugin

Tags: java, maven, doclet

I'm developing a maven plugin which uses the **com.sun.tools.javadoc** package.

In my Abstract mojo class I have this,

```
@Mojo(name = "scan")
public class GreetingMojo extends AbstractMojo {

    public void execute() throws MojoExecutionException {

    Main.execute(new String[]{"-doclet", "my.plugin.SimpleCheck", "-docletpath"
            , "."
            , "-sourcepath"
            , "./src/main/java"
            , "-subpackages"
            , "com.my.system"});
    }
}
```

In my SimpleCheck.java file I'm throwing the exception.

```
public class SimpleCheck {
    public static boolean start(RootDoc root) throws IOException, ParseException, MojoFailureException {
        throw new MojoFailureException("test");
    }
}
```

And as expected the exception is thrown.

```
javadoc: error - In doclet class my.plugin.SimpleCheck,  method start has thrown an exception java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoFailureException: test
........
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
1 error
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD SUCCESS
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.943 s
```

Why the build is still a success. Shouldn't the thrown exception fail the build. In the docs for **MojoFailureException** it says,

> An exception occurring during the execution of a plugin (such as a compilation failure).
>   Throwing this exception causes a "BUILD FAILURE" message to be displayed.

Why in this case it's not happening.

NOTE : I tried to throw the exception in my GreetingMojo.java class. Then the build got failed after throwing the exception.

```
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 0.467 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2017-12-25T22:44:36+05:30
[INFO] Final Memory: 5M/112M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal my.plugin:my-maven-plugin:1.0-SNAPSHOT:scan (default-cli) on project abcmanager: test throw in GreetingMojo -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```